# Uknown Issues while trying to use namespace in PHP

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm struggling to understand how to use namespace in PHP 7.4. But I meet issue, indeed, my Apache Server isn't able to use the class I specified the namespace.
About file tree : my "main" folder is called "Projects" and both "engine" and "LCDS" folders are at the same level into "Projects".

This is the class I'm trying to use:

```php
namespace engine\nodes;

public class footer{

    public function __construct($arrayDocs){
        $footer = '<div class="container-fluid" id="footer">
    <div class="container">';

    foreach ($arrayDocs as $doc=>$link){
        $footer.='<a href="'.$link.'">'.$doc.'</a><br>';
    }

    $footer .= '</div>
    <div class="container" id="copyright">
        La Cuisine des Seigneurs <strong>Copyright</strong> 2020 &copy
    </div>
</div>';
    }
    echo $footer;
}
```

and here's my folder in which I'm trying to use the class :

```php
use engine\nodes\footer;

$footer = new footer(['google'=>'https://www.google.fr']);
```

The error I get from my browser is : "Class 'engine\nodes\footer' not found"

May someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is the class in a folder called `nodes` under `engine`?

Comment: no, they're at the same level

Comment: You would normally reflect the directory structure with the namespace hierarchy, so try putting it in a nodes directory.

Comment: the fact is that i have to split the engine and it's countainer; So i cannot put them in the same file together

Comment: Do you have an autoloader defined that matches your directory structure? If not, PHP isn't going to take an educated guess as to where your class file is. You need to either register an autoloader or include your class file. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php